# Android: News feed from facebook wall to a android app without login

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Following is the code which I get from facebook developer console but it didn't work within my application.

```
String appToken = "app-id"+ "|" + "app-secret";
AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(appToken , "app-id", "fb-
page-
id-or-username", null, null, null, null, null);

GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
           accessToken,
           "/#{fb-page-id-or-username}/posts",
           new GraphRequest.Callback() {
               @Override
               public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                   // Insert your code here
                   Log.e("REPONSE", response.toString());
               }
           });

  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
  parameters.putString("fields", "attachments");
  request.setParameters(parameters);
  request.executeAsync();
```

Following is the response of above code:

**Response :-**

```
{
    Response:  responseCode: 400, 
    graphObject: null, 
    error: {
        HttpStatus: 400, 
        errorCode: 15, 
        errorType: OAuthException, 
        errorMessage: (#15) Requires session when calling from a desktop app
    }
}
```

Comment: what is not clear about the error? of course you need a user token to get access to the posts of a user.

Comment: I want to get facebook page fields without login. It works for desktop but not for device.